Java 22, Maven 3.9.9, MacBook Pro, and VSCode Error on running project
I'm running VSCode and I have Java 22 (22.0.2) installed on my MacBook Pro
below is my java --version...
java -version
openjdk version "22.0.2" 2024-07-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Homebrew (build 22.0.2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Homebrew (build 22.0.2, mixed mode, sharing)

...and my mvn --version
mvn -v
Apache Maven 3.9.9 (8e8579a9e76f7d015ee5ec7bfcdc97d260186937)
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.9.9/libexec
Java version: 22.0.2, vendor: Homebrew, runtime: /usr/local/Cellar/openjdk/22.0.2/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "14.6.1", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"

I set the JAVA_HOME PATH (in .zshrc) to...
echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/local/Cellar/openjdk/22.0.2/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home

I am creating a new Springboot application with maven in VSCode...
but when run the mvn command to clean the package - mvn clean package
...I get this error:
[INFO] --- compiler:3.13.0:compile (default-compile) @ api ---
[INFO] Recompiling the module because of changed source code.
[INFO] Compiling 3 source files with javac [debug parameters release 22.0.2] to target/classes
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.215 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-09-14T22:37:07-05:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.13.0:compile (default-compile) on project api: Fatal error compiling: error: release version 22.0.2 not supported -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

My pom.xml file looks like this:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.sample</groupId>
    <artifactId>api</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>api</name>
    <description>The Sample API</description>
    <url/>
    <licenses>
        <license/>
    </licenses>
    <developers>
        <developer/>
    </developers>
    <scm>
        <connection/>
        <developerConnection/>
        <tag/>
        <url/>
    </scm>
    <properties>
        <java.version>22.0.2</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
            <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
            <version>4.12.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.7.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.cdimascio</groupId>
            <artifactId>dotenv-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
        </dependency>       
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>

Can someone please help me to understand what's causing the error...

Does changing <java.version> to 22 (instead of 22.0.2) fix things?

First using the SNAPSHOT version of spring boot does not really make sense .. use release versions like 3.3.3 or 3.4.0-M1... Java version 22 instead of 22.0.2 and also remove all the hard coded version for jackson-core etc. because spring boot already defines them... remove all the SNAPSHOT/MILESTONE configurations for repositories.. (https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-parent/versions)

@khmarbaise 3.4.0-M1 is not a released version either, it is a development milestone version, and not suitable for use in production.

3.4.0-M1 is a milestone version which is a release... yes we can discuss about using such milestone in production...

Hello, this may be because of the Java version. You can try changing <java.version> to 22.

This issue is arising just because Maven is not recognizing the Java version 22.0.2, so I suggest you to replace your few line of pom.xml file as:
Prewritten by you:
<java.version>22.0.2</java.version>

Replace it with:
<java.version>22</java.version>

Along with this ensure that your Maven compiler plugin supports Java 22 by adding this plugin explicitly under :
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.10.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>22</source>
                <target>22</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- existing plugins -->
    </plugins>
</build>

In case you face any further issues then let me know.

No the configuration for the maven-compiler-plugin is not required ... because it's already done by the spring-boot-parent...

@khmarbaise Yes, you are correct the actual issue is with the java version property.

It's not related the configuration of maven-compiler-plugin is superfluous because the parent already defines it... apart from that you should use the release instead of source/target since JDK9+

The problem is not with Maven not recognizing 22.0.2, it is that the --release parameter of javac only accepts the major version (i.e. 22), as in it is the version of the Java language not the version of the JDK.
